Is the essential supremum of random variables with the same distribution the same?
If $X\ge 0$ is a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, $\hat{X}\ge 0$ is a random variable on $(\hat{\Omega}, \mathcal{\hat{F}}, \mathbb{\hat{P}})$, and $X$ and $\hat{X}$ have the same distribution, and $\hat{X} \leq 1$ almost surely with respect to $\mathbb{\hat{P}}$.
Can we conclude that $X \leq 1$ almost surely with respect to $\mathbb{P}$?
I can provide a proof, but I am unsure about it.
Since  $X$ and $\hat{X}$ have the same distribution, we have $||X||_n:=\mathbb
E[|X|^n]^{1/n}=\mathbb
{\hat E}[|\hat X|^n]^{1/n}=:|||\hat X|||_n$. Note that $||X||_n\rightarrow ||X||_\infty$ and $|||\hat X|||_n\rightarrow |||\hat X|||_\infty$, we have
$||X||_\infty=|||\hat X|||_\infty\le 1$, therefore, $X\le 1,\ \mathbb P-a.s..$

It is indeed true that the essential supremum are the same, since it depends on the distribution only. (In terms of the distribution itself, the essential supremum is the supremum of the support of the distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.) I am not sure about your proof, though, because it seems only working when $X$ is non-negative.

I am only concerned with the case where X is non-negative，I will revise the proposition.

A simpler proof would be that
$$\mathbb P[X\le1] = \hat{\mathbb P}[\hat X \le 1] =1.$$
